Why is the main breaker for my condo tripping?
My apartment was out of power and electrician came and reset the breaker and it continues to trip intermittently. Once it lasted 45 minutes; once it lasted three hours. (Bear in mind,these breakers are from 1957.) He replaced it and the electricity in my unit lasted about 24 hours. The electrician came back, the breaker was tripped, and he reset it.
I have electricity now, but I’m concerned it’s going to go out again because it tripped five times in the last three days and once since he replaced the breaker. He seems stymied and I called the city at his suggestion to ask them to to assess the meter. Any other places to check?

I have a feeling this will be closed because in a multi-unit building you can't DIY, and therefore not much to say here except "hope the electrician can figure it out". That being said, it seems odd to have a single breaker per apartment. Normally you would have an entire panel of breakers which in turn would have a main breaker and/or a feed breaker - and those main/feed breakers rarely trip. Something is missing here.

Is the breaker in question getting warm/hot when it trips?

Is your apartment the only one this breaker services, and is the main breaker, or only one circuit?  Have you added any new power draws to this circuit (especially ones that draw a lot of power like space heaters, etc.)  If your "electrician" hasn't done any more investigation than just resetting/replacing the breaker and crossing his fingers, get a new electrician that's more capable of troubleshooting your electrical situation.  It sounds like the breaker is probably doing its job to protect the wiring and your apartment from a very potential electrical fire from drawing too much power.

What size is the breaker?  What happens if you unplug everything in the apartment and plug it back in again?  What is your load calculation for your apartment?  This seems answerable.  Basically split your apartment into more circuits.  What's surprising is that the electrician hasn't already suggested that.

A breaker tripping usually means it is doing its job to protect you.   The timing it trips is more in line with an overload in the wires, so have you started to use a electrical device, either a old one and using for the season change, or a new one?

Did the electrician walk through your apartment and look at anything? If not, you need to pressure building management to get somebody competent.

A breaker can trip due to heat generated in poor connection on the supply or load side. If the electrician didn't verify those to be clean and snug, and use a torque wrench as appropriate, then the replacement workmanship might be faulty.

@AloysiusDefenestrate Everything inside a condo is typically the owner's responsibility. The OP likely needs to hire an electrician at their own expense, if a fault outside of their uint has been ruled out.

My bad… I saw ‘apartment’ in the body text and missed ‘condo’ in the title.

A bit of an assumption here based on typical apartments/condos that I have seen, but which may or may not be the situation here.
A typical setup is to have a large electric supply (possibly even 3-phase) coming in to an electrical room. From there it feeds a meter and a main breaker/disconnect for each unit. Either in that same room or, preferably, in each unit in user-accessible space, is a panel with breakers for each circuit.
Based on the description, the main breaker for a unit has been tripping and that is what the electrician has been resetting and even replacing. A main breaker can trip for two reasons:

It is failing

The right thing to do is replace it.

There is too much electricity in use

The right thing to do is to figure out why there is a lot of electricity being used. That may be actual appliances, particularly anything that generates heat such as space heaters, oven, water heater, etc. Or it may be due to the very dangerous situation of damaged wire connections overheating, which can use enough electricity to trip a breaker and to start a fire. Having just seen this morning what can happen when a simple exhaust fan overheats and starts a fire, I can tell you this is a very real concern.
Get the electrician out again. After he resets the breaker, ask him to put a clamp meter on the feed wires to see how much power is being used. Then turn on all the things you might typically have on when the breaker trips and see how much power is being used. If, for example, the results show 50A in use on a 100A breaker then there may be something else very strange going on. On the other hand, if the results show 80A in use on a 60A breaker then you have your answer. 80A on a 60A breaker will not trip instantly, but it will trip eventually, as long as the breaker is functioning properly.

Had the exact thing happen to us - our main breaker (30 years old) in the apartment building would trip if we had the dryer on for a while. The electrician clamped our wires and it was only drawing 30 amps on a 100 amp service. Tripped again but this time there was burnt electrical smell in the electrical room. Turns out the breaker was failing, heating up and tripping on high temp. Had to replace the main breaker asap.
